# SQL Server group by foreign key and select dependant columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have some performance issues when querying in SQL server. I need to GROUP BY foreign key (academic_unit_id), but I also need to select a column that is dependant on  the FK (academic_unit_name).
In SQL Server I can't just select academic_unit_name in the same query, it must be aggregated or in the GROUP BY.
I think the options I have are:

1. SELECT academic_unit_id (foreign key) and academic_unit_unit_name (dependant on FK), and then group by both

```
SELECT 
    ria.COD_DOCENTE_SCD,
    ria.COD_CURSO_SECCION_SCD,
    ria.COD_ITEM_SCD,
    ria.COD_GRUPO_PREGUNTA_SCD,
    alumno.IDN_UNIDAD_ACADEM_SCD, -- id
    alumno.NOM_UNIDAD_ACADEM_SCD, -- name
    ROUND(COUNT(case when opcion.punto = 1 then 1 end), 2) as amount_yes,
    ROUND(COUNT(case when opcion.punto = 0 then 1 end), 2) as amount_no
FROM BANNER_ENCUESTA.R_RESP_ITEM_ALUMNO_CSP_SCD AS ria INNER JOIN
    BANNER_ENCUESTA.TIPO_OPCION_SCD AS opcion ON ria.COD_TIPO_OPCION_SCD = opcion.COD_TIPO_OPCION_SCD INNER JOIN
    BANNER_ENCUESTA.ALUMNO_SCD AS alumno ON ria.COD_ALUMNO_SCD = alumno.COD_ALUMNO_SCD
GROUP BY 
    ria.COD_DOCENTE_SCD,
    ria.COD_CURSO_SECCION_SCD,
    ria.COD_ITEM_SCD,
    ria.COD_GRUPO_PREGUNTA_SCD,
    alumno.IDN_UNIDAD_ACADEM_SCD, -- group by FK
    alumno.NOM_UNIDAD_ACADEM_SCD -- group by name
```

2. GROUP BY PK and aggregate the academic_unit_name. I can aggregate using max, since all names are equals for a given id.

```
SELECT 
    ria.COD_DOCENTE_SCD,
    ria.COD_CURSO_SECCION_SCD,
    ria.COD_ITEM_SCD,
    ria.COD_GRUPO_PREGUNTA_SCD,
    alumno.IDN_UNIDAD_ACADEM_SCD, -- id
    MAX(alumno.NOM_UNIDAD_ACADEM_SCD), -- aggregate name
    ROUND(COUNT(case when opcion.punto = 1 then 1 end), 2) as amount_yes,
    ROUND(COUNT(case when opcion.punto = 0 then 1 end), 2) as amount_no
FROM BANNER_ENCUESTA.R_RESP_ITEM_ALUMNO_CSP_SCD AS ria INNER JOIN
    BANNER_ENCUESTA.TIPO_OPCION_SCD AS opcion ON ria.COD_TIPO_OPCION_SCD = opcion.COD_TIPO_OPCION_SCD INNER JOIN
    BANNER_ENCUESTA.ALUMNO_SCD AS alumno ON ria.COD_ALUMNO_SCD = alumno.COD_ALUMNO_SCD
GROUP BY 
    ria.COD_DOCENTE_SCD,
    ria.COD_CURSO_SECCION_SCD,
    ria.COD_ITEM_SCD,
    ria.COD_GRUPO_PREGUNTA_SCD,
    alumno.IDN_UNIDAD_ACADEM_SCD --Group by FK
```

3. SELECT only academic_unit_id and then JOIN with AcademicUnit again to obtain the name.

```
with banner_questions as (
SELECT 
    ria.COD_DOCENTE_SCD,
    ria.COD_CURSO_SECCION_SCD,
    ria.COD_ITEM_SCD,
    ria.COD_GRUPO_PREGUNTA_SCD,
    alumno.IDN_UNIDAD_ACADEM_SCD -- id,
    ROUND(COUNT(case when opcion.punto = 1 then 1 end), 2) as amount_yes,
    ROUND(COUNT(case when opcion.punto = 0 then 1 end), 2) as amount_no
FROM BANNER_ENCUESTA.R_RESP_ITEM_ALUMNO_CSP_SCD AS ria INNER JOIN
    BANNER_ENCUESTA.TIPO_OPCION_SCD AS opcion ON ria.COD_TIPO_OPCION_SCD = opcion.COD_TIPO_OPCION_SCD INNER JOIN
    BANNER_ENCUESTA.ALUMNO_SCD AS alumno ON ria.COD_ALUMNO_SCD = alumno.COD_ALUMNO_SCD
GROUP BY 
    ria.COD_DOCENTE_SCD,
    ria.COD_CURSO_SECCION_SCD,
    ria.COD_ITEM_SCD,
    ria.COD_GRUPO_PREGUNTA_SCD,
    alumno.IDN_UNIDAD_ACADEM_SCD) -- group by FK
SELECT
    banner_questions.*,
    student_ua.name -- Join with name
from NORMALIZADO_PRELIMINAR.AcademicUnit as student_ua INNER JOIN
    banner_questions on student_ua.id = banner_questions.IDN_UNIDAD_ACADEM_SCD
```

In terms of performance, I'd like to know if one of these alternatives is better and under what assummptions. Also, I'd like to know if there are better choices to get the same result.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Why do you _need to GROUP BY primary key_? A PK has all unique values, so a GROUP BY makes no sense.

Comment: (1) `group by` a primary key does not make a lot of sense; each row will end up in a separate group anyway (2) SQL Server does not understand the notion of functionally dependent columns (3) Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your question.

Comment: Ok, give me a minute, I'll show the examples

Comment: I agree with @seanb, probably depends on indexes available, which columns are included. I've always done group by both fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question I think you mean `Foreign key` rather than `Primary key`... the field is a Primary key in another table `Academic_unit` but is looking at, say, student_unit records which have an FK to Academic_unit.

So the question is for the field `alumno.NOM_UNIDAD_ACADEM_SCD` - do you `GROUP BY` it, `MAX()` it or `JOIN` it later?

Personally I suggest just

- trying all three and see which ones run the fastest - which is best really depends on specific circumstances - and they often run very similarly
- use the simplest version if they run at similar speeds - which is likely to be the GROUP BY version

In particular, the GROUP BY and MAX() should result in almost identical plans as they are sorted the same way.

The 'join it later' approach *can* have some speed advantages in certain circumstances (particularly when it's not just being joined to a reference table, but to a broader set of sub-queries), but I'm often wary about these. They have the disadvantage of making your code a bit more complex - which can have issues if you use the data for other things, or if SQL Server has bad estimates for the amount of data it expects. In this case, as this is just linking to the reference table `alumno`, it's unlikely to give any specific advantage.

In your code for option 3 above, you still have links to `BANNER_ENCUESTA.ALUMNO_SCD AS alumno`. The advantage of doing the join later would be to remove that from the initial grouping component, then link to it later to get the specific values e.g.,

- In the GROUP BY within the CTE, also group by `ria.COD_ALUMNO_SCD`, but remove `BANNER_ENCUESTA.ALUMNO_SCD AS alumno` from the FROM clause
- Put `BANNER_ENCUESTA.ALUMNO_SCD AS alumno` into the main SELECT part of the query, and join to `banner_questions` on that field

Note there is also a fourth option (temporary tables) which is used when

- SQL Server gets estimates for how many rows it expects really wrong - and makes a really bad plan
- You're joining not to reference tables, but to views (particularly if they have 'TOP' expressions or 'GROUP BY' in them) - in these cases, SQL Server may sometimes run the view completely once for every row in the join.

In these cases, it can be useful to split the query into two parts along the lines of #3, but instead of a CTE, you save it into a temporary table e.g., `SELECT .... INTO #temp FROM ... GROUP BY`.

You then use the temporary table, joined to the view that was problematic, and it will often run better.

Comment: JOIN later seems to be the fastest approach. (50% faster).
I'm using this query as a base for a longer query

Comment: That is surprising - is `BANNER_ENCUESTA.ALUMNO_SCD` a view rather than a table? (I assumed it was a table as we were talking PKs/FKs)

Comment: It's a table. 
About the improvement you suggested, I need to keep the group by alumno.IDN_UNIDAD_ACADEM_SCD within the CTE as I need some calculated columns I ommited

Comment: OK... anyway, it is very dependent on circumstances. If it works well for you, then that's great!